# Fetch works on local server but not online server, and only for one api call

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, fetch

A react page runs two fetch calls to my nodejs server. On localhost it works perfectly, but once I push to the web it only works for one call, but not the other.

The syntax for these calls are exactly the same. I checked the mySQL statements and they work in workbench.

I've tried making it synchronous so that it fetches first the call that doesn't seem to be working, but it still gives the same erorr:

```
Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Going to the network console on Chrome shows an empty preview for the fetch call that isn't working, and the one that is working is showing my data.

On localhost, but fetch calls show data in the preview.

Here's my syntax for making the call:

```
new Promise((res,rej) =>{
      fetch('/api/call1?id='+id)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(call1Data => (
        res(call1Data) )
      ).catch((error) => {
        console.error("error",error);

    })

    }).then((call1Data)=> {

      fetch('/api/call2?id='+id)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(call2Data => (

          this.setState({  call2Data: call2Data, call1Data : call1Data))}) , console.log("finished") )
          ).catch((error) => {
          console.error("error",error);

      })
  })
```

On node's side, the syntax for each call is exactly the same except for the SQL statement, which I've already tested each statement in workbench.

Comment: `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` usually means that there is a server-side failure, as it's returning your server's error page which begins with an `<html>` tag.  Your React is attempting to process it as JSON, which it is not, as it's a server-side error page.  Double-check your network tab, and make sure there are no filters as you should be able to see exactly what request is failing and check from that error.

Comment: Use your browser's development tool for inspecting the response

Comment: what do you mean by “no filters”?

Comment: So in Chrome DevTools (which I'm hoping that you're using), on the "Network" tab, there is a filter box on top where you can filter by method, request URI, etc. -- make sure this box is blank, and that the buttons to the right of it, you have "All" selected, to ensure that you aren't filtering out any requests.  You then should be able to see the failing call (which will show in red) and determine what that error page is saying--hopefully it should give you more details.